# Why Won't Supertux Level Editor Compile on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, compiling, monodevelop

I should have the latest files from supertux wiki. I've compiled the game itself, but the editor has problems compiling.

Here's the error I get:

```
MonoCSharp Lisp.dll
make: gmcs: Command not found
make: *** [Lisp.dll] Error 127
```

I have Monodevelop installed, but it still seems like I'm missing some dependencies.

Comment: Try first installing build-essential `sudo apt-get install build-essential`. It installs a little more then you probably need, but it is an easy single command. You then need to install the dependencies, which typically involves installing the -dev packages.

Comment: I see that /usr/bin/gmcs is in the mono-gmcs package, do you have that installed?

Comment: Mono-gmcs package? Can I simply apt-get the packages? I have installed build-essential, but not the mono-gmcs packages. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Yes, `sudo apt-get install mono-gmcs`

Answer (score 0):

You can install the latest GIT of supertux-editor from the [ppa:landronimirc/supertux-git](https://launchpad.net/~landronimirc/+archive/supertux-git).